# Zuul routes redirect issue in chrome browser

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

> I have deployed one application on GKE GCP
> Front end is in
> Angular and backend is spring boot with version 2.6.7 and spring
> clound version 2021.0.5. The flows goes from front end to backend and
> in the backend Zuul gateway will redirect the request to the different
> server which is on-prem. The application is getting successful
> response from the on-prem server on the edge browser but in the chrome
> browser it is failing. We have checked the on-prem server logs, extra
> https is getting added in the API url when we are hitting the
> application url in the chrome browser. The same extra https is not
> getting added when we are hitting it from the edge browser. The error
> stack from the on-prem server is given below.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not get HttpServletRequest URI: Illegal character in scheme name at index 5: `https,https://<IP>/abc/def/xyz`
at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpRequest.getURI(ServletServerHttpRequest.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpRequest(UriComponentsBuilder.java:282) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.isSameOrigin(WebUtils.java:814) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]

> Has anyone else also faced similar kind of issue?

Comment: Spring Cloud Netflix Zuul is no longer supported and is not compatible with any projects in Spring Cloud 2021.x. We strongly recommend migrating out of it as using non-maintained libraries poses security issues. We recommend using Spring Cloud Gateway instead.

Comment: I tried with spring cloud gateway too, facing same error.

Comment: I think you might be using mismatched project versions. Please use start.spring.io to generate a correct build file. If the problem persists, you should create an issue in Spring Cloud GateWay repo with a sample that reproduces the problem.